# Kommt da ein Komma hin?

Tags: comma

Should there be a comma:

> Ihr sowas Schreckliches mitteilen zu müssen(,) ist echt kein schönes Gefühl.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where German Grammar actually allows you the matter of taste - You may or may not separate an infinitive clause.

Comment: @tofro: This is not correct. The infinite group dependes on a noun (Gefühl), and in this case a comma is required.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Offizielle deutsche Rechtschreibregeln §76 - "**kann**".

Comment: @tofro, ich weiß nicht welche Version Sie da haben, aber in der aktuellen des Rechtschreiberats steht: “_§ 76 Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden Bedingungen erfüllt ist. (2) die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Substantiv ab_“. Die Ausbahme E1, die das Weglassen erlauben könnte, gilt ja hier nicht, da die Bedingung **bloßer Infinitiv** nicht vorliegt. http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The *»zu«* before an infinitive is a signal word for an infinitive clause. You can always disconnect the infinitive clause with a comma.

A comma is required

- when the infinitive clause is introduced with *um*, *ohne*, *statt*, *anstatt*, *außer* or *als*, e.g.:

  > Ich komme, **um** mich zu beschweren.
- when the infinitive clause depends on a noun, e.g.:

  > Ich habe die **Absicht**, mich zu beschweren.

It is advisable to always set a comma to clarify the structure of a sentence.

Comment: Fun fact: According to the pre-1996 rules, the comma was forbidden in this special case (infinitive sentence that precedes the main clause’s verb and functions as the subject). Just an example of how complex the comma rules and exceptions used to be before the spelling reform.